# Easy References for understanding Grossmann and Larson rooted trees?

Tags: trees, hopf-algebras

I am an undergraduate student doing a project on rooted trees. I was wondering if anyone would know any easy to understand references that explains Grossman and Larson's Hopf Algebra on rooted trees? In particular, I want to know how the comultiplication, counit, and antipode are defined. Maybe if there is anything that explains their paper 'Hopf-algebraic structures of families of trees'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Varilly et. al.'s [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=O8_TBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA613&lpg=PA613&dq=varilly%20grossman%20larson&source=bl&ots=IOHmgQ_8TT&sig=cNxnJRCw7SlhyX_jflaYqjmo-Yw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj31Mq4zcLNAhUHKY8KHaJQA98Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=varilly%20grossman%20larson&f=false) and also see this paper

http://cds.cern.ch/record/848107/files/cer-002531441.pdf

Comment: Though your link may answer the question, it is always good to include the essential part in your answer